Is there a way to check the comments of local variables when hovering over them in Visual Studio 2022?
using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition.
Write XML comments on fields, methods, classes, etc., and display those comments in a tooltip that appears when you hover over the variable.
However, local variables are not displayed.
Is it possible to display comments for local variables in this tooltip as well?


I tried the method below :

(1) is a field.
The rest are local variables.


Code for quick testing (C#):

class Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A summary
    /// </summary>
    public int A;

    public Test()
    {
        // B summary
        int B;

        int C; // C summary

        /// <summary>
        /// D summary
        /// </summary>
        int D;

        this.A = 1;
        B = 2;
        C = 3;
        D = 4;

        if (B == C || C == D)
        {

        }
    }
}


There's no concept of XML comments for local variables so there's nothing built to consume them. In general, the tooltip is there to help you see some documentation for potentially "far away" definitions. If you cannot see the definition of the local within your current code window, it suggests the method may be too large. And/or that better naming of the variables themselves would improve matters.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm aware of the methodological solution to this issue.
However, reality does not always unfold according to the methodological approach.
While separating the code can sometimes lead to more ambiguous code or make debugging more difficult, and using an integer instead of declaring an enumeration that is only used locally to avoid the tedious task, such pragmatic decisions often occur in the field.

I'm not saying that the methodological approach is inherently wrong.
The methodological solution is not always the absolute best answer, which is why I'm raising this question.
